# DataSources in Infor Saleslogix

Tags: c#, saleslogix

I am writing my first web Application in Sales Logix.

I am trying to map fields from an already working Windows application to the Web version and it doesnt appear to be correct.

In the database Manager I have one list of mappings and in the Web Manager Application Archiect I have MainEntity, but I have no way of editing this data?

Does anyone know how to modify this list, spent half a day searching for this info

Comment: Have you made any progress on this issue?  Could you add details?

Answer (score 0):

Database manager is pulling the field list from the database.  Entity properties are separately maintained in Application Architect.

To update the properties of an entity, right mouse click on the entity and select `update properties...`.

You then get a list of entity properties compared to the database table.

You can then add new entity properties by selecting the database columns you want to add.